# An elegant way to throw global errors from a Symfony custom validator?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, validation

I'm using Symfony 1.4 to allow users to import various types of CSV files, and I've decided to consolidate validation and sanitizing of the actual contents of uploaded files into a custom validator - The custom validator would extend sfValidatorFile.

Also, when a file contains errors, I'd like to throw global errors on forms, rather than displaying them as field/local errors - and - have the ability to show many validation errors at the same time for a given import file.

I'm pretty sure I can make this work by using a Post Validator, but this doesn't seem like a great fit for a Post Validator (since I really only need knowledge of one form field in order to perform my custom validation), but more importantly, I'd like something a bit more elegant that packages all of the extra validation work into a single custom file validator.

For example, instead of:

```
$this->validatorSchema['file'] = new sfValidatorFile( … );
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new myFancyValidator( … ));
```

I'd just like to do something like:

```
$this->validatorSchema['file'] = new myFancyValidator( … );
```

...and have validation errors encountered inside myFancyValidator added to the form's collection of global errors.

I've tried a few different approaches to push errors onto the form's globalErrors from within my custom validator, but I'm missing something regarding how the various pieces of the validation puzzle fit/scope together. Any thoughts as to how to accomplish this? Dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

Throw a sfValidatorError object in your custom validator, e.g. :

```
if(!$isValid){
    // throw global error
    throw new sfValidatorError($this, "invalid");
}
else {
    return true;
}
```